# Почему не подставляется переменная в Nginx?

Tags: nginx

Так не работает (502 ошибка):

```
location / {
    set $prpr http://localhost:10001;
    proxy_pass $prpr;
}
```

Так работает:

```
location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:10001;
}
```

Comment: Что при этом пишет в /var/log/nginx/*error.log?

Comment: 2018/03/13 13:42:02 [error] 23887#23887: *2 no resolver defined to resolve localhost, client:

Comment: В hosts есть запись о localhost?
Не пробовали записать как 127.0.0.1, или [::1]?

Comment: Да, изменил на 127.0.0.1 заработало, вот тут вроде есть объяснение https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213902445-Website-shows-502-Bad-Gateway-no-resolver-defined-to-resolve-example-com

Comment: Укажите перед `upstream` какой нибудь dns в виде `resolver 8.8.8.8;`

Answer (score 1):

Не работает, т.к. в proxy_pass - [указывается протокол](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass), т. е. "http://" или "https://". Попробуйте объявить только адрес, без протокола.

```
location / {
    set $prpr localhost:10001;
    proxy_pass http://$prpr;
}
```

На мой взгляд стоит использовать для этой цели [upstream](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html).

```
upstream backend {
    server unix:/tmp/myapplication.socket fail_timeout=5s; # primary
    server localhost:10001 backup;                         # fallback server
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

Если вопрос в том чтобы указывать backend динамически (в зависимости от ссылки) то, вот так:

```
resolver 8.8.8.8;

upstream site {
    server unix:/tmp/site.socket;
    server 127.0.0.1:10001;
    server mysite.local resolve;
}

upstream apiv1 {
    server unix:/tmp/api.socket;
    server 127.0.0.1:10002;
    server myapi.local resolve;
}

location ~ ^/api/v1/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://api;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://site;
}
```

Comment: Нет, вопрос в том, как из system environment variable достать порт для проксирования. Ничего кроме как с помощью lua, я не нашел, решил инклюдить конфиг

Comment: Ваш вариант тоже не работает(

Comment: Можно создать свой unit для systemd, хоть это и костыль, или упаковать nginx в docker. Хотелось бы полностью увидеть конфиг, или более конкретное описание задачи.

Comment: а вот чем докер поможет, если в конфиге nginx все равно нельзя использовать environment variables? Каким еще путем туда прокинуть нужный конфиг динамически?

Comment: Можно использовать какой нибудь docker-entrypoint.sh и ему передавать набор ENV

Comment: Ну в докер понятно как передавать, а в nginx то как получить в конфиге

Comment: У nginx dockerfile есть неплохая документация на этот счет. https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/nginx#using-environment-variables-in-nginx-configuration

Comment: Хм, да, спасибо, поизучаю, выглядит не очень вкусно конечно)

Answer (score 0):

Помогло, изменение localhost на 127.0.0.1 или можно отрезолвить как где написано

```
http {
    resolver 127.0.0.1;
```

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213902445-Website-shows-502-Bad-Gateway-no-resolver-defined-to-resolve-example-com